# MySQL Cross Join with concat field

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

I have 2 tables in a MySQL database: `Products` and `ProductsType`.

Each element of the `Products` table has a type which is contained in `ProductsType` table.
Each table has a field named "code".

I'd like to have a `VIEW` with the cartesian product of these 2 tables and I know that I can do it with a `CROSS JOIN`.

But I'd like that in this VIEW I can see the CONCAT of the 2 fields named "code" of my 2 tables. Is that possible?

I've also thought that I can make 3 tables, `Products`, `ProductsType` and `ProductsWithType` and in the first 2 I put some triggers "after insert" that keep updated the third table `ProductsWithType`, but I'd like to know if it is possibile to do with a view.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
CREATE VIEW vw_products_types AS
SELECT CONCAT(p.code, t.code) combined_code, p.product_name, t.type_name
  FROM Products p CROSS JOIN ProductsType t
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06b33/1)** demo